# Assigning rails association using strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have two models and one belongs to another. Now normaly you would assign an object to the association when populating the fields. Does rails allow overriding the set method so that the association assignment can be customised?

E.g

```
class Person
  # something about shirts
end

class Shirt
  belongs_to :person

  def person=(p)
    self.person = Person.find_or_create_by_name(p)
  end
end
```

And then use something like so auto bind the association but using a string to do the searching and binding automatically. Is this possible?

s = Shirt.new

s.person = "Test Person"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ROR Guides cover the [association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) you need.

UPDATE:
Actually, overriding setter is not that bad, once you understand what you're doing. But you have to be careful, since it can cause infinite loop (as in your example). So if you're using Rails 3.2, you have to [use `super`](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2012/1/20/modularized-association-methods-in-rails-3-2), in other case you have to use [alias_method_chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283046/problem-with-setter-override-on-activerecord).

Comment: Thanks for that, must have missed the link. The link describes how to make new methods in addition. It is considered bad practice to override the Rails association setter? As this is what I was originally trying to do

Comment: @Onyth  I've added explanations on that

Comment: thanks for the explanation. This most definitely clears up my little misunderstanding with the AR association methods.